# Meteor Mongo - Database Storage location

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I tried to sync my project via git hub between my laptop and my desktop PC, but when i pull the work on my laptop that i pushed from my desktop i have absolutely no entries in my database, which i added on my desktop PC. No users, nothing.

I thought the database is stored in the .meteor folder and it would be available but it seems i was wrong.

**Question:** Where is the database from meteor located so i can push it to git hub too?

Thanks for your help!

Muff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Meteor mongo store on .meteor/local/db folders, If you are not setting your mongo_url in your system.

But if you are facing this problem,then I think you .gitingore file contains the .meteor/local/db folder or may be your mongopath is different.

Comment: You were right! Inside the .meteor folder there was another .gitignore file with content "local", so the whole local-folder has been ignored. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You are right. It will be under `.meteor` folder. It is `.meteor/local/db`.